# Autoencoder pytorch requiring retain_graph = True in loss.backward()

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have the following simple autoencoder:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, model_config):
        super().__init__()

        output_features = model_config["output_features"]
        encode2_size = model_config["encode2_size"]
        encode3_size = model_config["encode3_size"]

        # define encoding layers
        self.encode1 = nn.Linear(input_shape, output_features)
        self.encode2 = nn.Linear(output_features, encode2_size)
        self.encode3 = nn.Linear(encode2_size, encode3_size)

        # define decoding layers
        self.decode1 = nn.Linear(encode3_size, encode2_size)
        self.decode2 = nn.Linear(encode2_size, output_features)
        self.decode3 = nn.Linear(output_features, input_shape)

    def encode(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        x = relu(self.encode1(x))
        x = relu(self.encode2(x))
        x = relu(self.encode3(x))
        return x

    def decode(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        x = relu(self.decode1(x))
        x = relu(self.decode2(x))
        x = relu(self.decode3(x))
        return x

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor):
        x = self.encode(x)
        x = self.decode(x)
        return x
```

I am using dice loss shown below:

```
class DiceLoss(nn.Module):
    """
    The formula: 2*|X ∩ Y|/(|X|*|Y|)
    """

    def __init__(self, weight=None, size_average=True):
        super(DiceLoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, inputs, targets, smooth=1):
        # comment out if your model contains a sigmoid acitvation
        inputs = torch.sigmoid(inputs)

        # flatten label and prediction tensors
        inputs = inputs.view(-1)
        targets = targets.view(-1)

        intersection = (inputs * targets).sum()
        dice = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (inputs.sum() + targets.sum() + smooth)

        return 1 - dice
```

For training I have something like this:

```
train_sampler = DistributedSampler(data_tensor, num_replicas=hvd.size(), rank=hvd.rank())
train_dataloader = DataLoader(data_tensor, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, sampler=train_sampler)

# autoencoder params
epochs = model_config["epochs"]
net = Autoencoder(embedding_dim, model_config)

# loss function and optimizer
loss_function = DiceLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adagrad(net.parameters(), lr=model_config["lr"], weight_decay=model_config["weight_decay"])


for epoch in range(epochs):

        for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            net.zero_grad()

            # Pass batch through
            output = net(batch)


            # Get Loss + Backprop
            loss = loss_function(output, batch)

            
            loss.backward(retain_graph=True) 
            optimizer.step()
```

Without `retain_graph=True` I get the error:

> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

I understand the issue.  To reduce memory usage, during the `.backward()` call, all the intermediary results are deleted when they are not needed anymore. Hence if you try to call `.backward()` again, the intermediary results don't exist and the backward pass cannot be performed (and you get the error). You can call `.backward(retain_graph=True)` to make a backward pass that will not delete intermediary results, and so you will be able to call `.backward()` again. All but the last call to backward should have the `retain_graph=True` option.

If I use `retain_graph=True`, I run into OOM issues.  How can I change the code here to avoid `retain_graph=True`?  Thanks.

Comment: Does it persist with the default dataloader sampler (shuffle =True)? This is the only part with looks remotely suspicious to me.

Comment: Isn't the default False?  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html

Comment: I will set to true and see what happens though.

Comment: Uhm, I meant to get rid of the `DistributedSampler`. I thought `sampler=` is mutually exclusive with `shuffle=` but maybe my memory serves me wrong.